# How Can I Configure Standing Order (Repeat Same Products Order Every Month to sent customer via Mail)

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-email, recurring, send-mail

Initially `customer able to selected products for standing Order list`, Every month starting customer get alert for `"Your Monthly Alert"` via E-mail. How can i configure standing order.

Comment: Do you want to create orders as well or just an alert email?

Comment: @BGKavinga : Initially customer add all their products in standing order, then automatically send mail to customer, no matter on that time some other products in addtocart. customer get their standing order, optionally customer get their addtocart products also.

Answer (score 0):

This is very brief and vague, so my answer will be the same. Magento itself does not support such functionality, however you can leverage the 'reorder' functionality Magento has built in. You have multiple options:

1. Create a custom module. This is by far the most time consuming and requires a good knowledge of backend development however you can build it to suite your needs. This module will need to allow customers to 'register' their cart for recurring ordering, they need to insert a date at which to begin the next cycle. Save the order ID and date into the database, associated to that customer ID. Create a cron that runs every morning, which loops through all customers that have registered and date is equal to current date. Then shoot through an email to these customers with a link. This link will take them to a page that will leverage the built-in Magento reorder functionality by automatically adding the products of that order to their cart. This will only work after they have checked out and created the order first.
2. Leverage an extension i.e. [Recurring Orders](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/recurring-orders-and-subscriptions.html), you may need to modify the extension to work as you like however I think this may do exactly what you require, if not more. If you do not want recurring payment or orders automatically placed then this may be overkill and you have to check if you can disable those features within this extension.